# Set an application's resource limits (CPU usage)

Tags: windows, compression, limit, cpu-usage, winrar

It's a little strange I know,
but I want to limit a program (for example the winrar app) resource usage.

**The reason:**
I have an old laptop, with overheating problem, so if I want to do a calculate intensive task (compress a >10GB folder), my laptop overheats and turns off.

**The question:**
Is it possible to limit an application's resource/CPU usage? For example, can I set somehow, that winrar can only use my CPU's 50%?

I use windows 8.1,
but answer for other OS is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Are there solutions that can limit the CPU usage of a process?](https://superuser.com/questions/214566/are-there-solutions-that-can-limit-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process) for general answer.

**WinRAR** itself has the command line switch `-ri`, see in help of **WinRAR** the page with title:

```
Switch -RI<p>[:<s>] - set priority and sleep time
```

For example using a command line like

```
WinRAR.exe a -ri1:100 Backup.rar *
```

results in compressing all files in current working directory with default settings using lowest task priority and with 100 ms sleep time between each read or write operation.