# Can I queue WinRAR?

Tags: batch-file, packing, winrar

Is there a way I can queue WinRAR packing, so it does one job at the time, not all at once slowing down my CPU?

I have a lot of big files that must be splitted up into a SFX and they should not be bigger that 400 MB. I can do the job doing it file by file, but that takes a lot of time, so if I just could run a batch in the evening my PC could do all the job while I sleep.

Comment: I'd suggest improving your question by indicating the batch language you are using -- command line versions of Rar are available for Windows, Android, Linux and OS X.  Assuming you're using windows, this question may apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214318/set-an-applications-resource-limits-cpu-usage

Comment: No, that is not the problem. I have, lets say 10 files (huge, over 2GB each), i want them to be sfx-rar, but i dont want to do it manually, i want it to take one file at the time. so when the first is finished, the seccond starts and so on. That way i can start it in the evening and it will be done in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't need a batch. It can be done with GUI of WinRAR.

1. I just select my files.
2. Right click and choose **Add files to archive**.
3. Go to tab **Files** and check *Put each file to separate archive*.

Thats it. WinRAR packs now one file after the other and creates for each file a separate archive as documented on help page opened on pressing button **Help** on tab **Files**.

Comment: This is the right method for your task. But to answer your initial question, there is also the option *Wait if other WinRAR copies are active* on tab **Advanced** to queue several WinRAR processes?